# How to add an item to a list in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, collections, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to add an element list to the list of string, but I found `Kotlin` does not have an add function like `java` so please help me out how to add the items to the list.

```
class RetrofitKotlin : AppCompatActivity() {

    var listofVechile:List<Message>?=null
    var listofVechileName:List<String>?=null
    var listview:ListView?=null
    var progressBar:ProgressBar?=null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit_kotlin)

        listview=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.mlist)
        var apiInterfacee=ApiClass.client.create(ApiInterfacee::class.java)
        val call=apiInterfacee.getTaxiType()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<TaxiTypeResponse> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<TaxiTypeResponse>, response: Response<TaxiTypeResponse>) {

                listofVechile=response.body()?.message!!
                println("Sixze is here listofVechile   ${listofVechile!!.size}")
                if (listofVechile!=null) {
                    for (i in 0..listofVechile!!.size-1) {

                        //how to add the name only listofVechileName list

                    }
                }
                //println("Sixze is here ${listofVechileName!!.size}")
                val arrayadapter=ArrayAdapter<String>(this@RetrofitKotlin,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,listofVechileName)
                listview!!.adapter=arrayadapter

            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<TaxiTypeResponse>, t: Throwable) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: huh?  what list are you talking about?  Kotlin lists ARE Java lists, aren't they?   I'm sorry if the foreign names are throwing me off.

Comment: @Steve I'm talking about var listofVechileName:List<String>?=null  how to add the item  on it

Comment: You need to take a step back, and read the documentation to learn the fundamentals of Kotlin, by simply reading the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html

Comment: Ah yes...the immutable thing.  I just didn't put 2 and 2 together on this one.  Makes perfect, obvious sense.  I don't get to do enough Kotlin coding yet.  It's not about reading the docs.  Rather, it's about doing your day job in Java, and having to pull your head out of that and think in Kotlin.

Comment: A simple answer, **you can't** directly add items to **List** without converting it to its mutable form.

Answer (score 81):

Talking about an idiomatic approach...

When you can get away with only using **immutable** lists (which means *usually* in Kotlin), simply use `+` or [`plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html). It returns a new list 
with all elements of the original list plus the newly added one:

```
val original = listOf("orange", "apple")
val modified = original + "lemon" // [orange, apple, lemon]
```

`original.plus("lemon")` yields the same result as `original + "lemon"`. Slightly more verbose but might come in handy when combining several collection operations:

```
return getFruit()
       .plus("lemon")
       .distinct()
```

Besides adding a single element, you can use `plus` to concatenate a whole collection too:

```
val original = listOf("orange", "apple")
val other = listOf("banana", "strawberry")
val newList = original + other // [orange, apple, banana, strawberry]
```

Disclaimer: this doesn't directly answer OP's question, but I feel that in a question titled "How to add an item to a list in Kotlin?", which is a top Google hit for this topic, `plus` *must* be mentioned.

Comment: The one thing with `.plus()` is that it has to be a MutableList. Regular List doesn't implement that.

Comment: @JayWhitsitt That is incorrect. Please try running the code examples in my answer. For example `listOf` returns a read-only list, yet you absolutely can call `plus()` on that. As I mentioned above, `plus` returns a new list; it never modifies the original list.

Answer (score 75):

A more idiomatic approach would be to use `MutableList` instead of specifically `ArrayList`. You can declare:

```
val listOfVehicleNames: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
```

And add to it that way. Alternatively, you may wish to prefer immutability, and declare it as:

```
var listOfVehicleNames: List<String> = emptyList()
```

And in your completion block, simply reassign it:

```
listOfVehicleNames = response.body()?.message()?.orEmpty()
    .map { it.name() /* assumes name() function exists */ }
```

Answer (score 53):

If you don't want or can't use array list directly use this code for add item

```
itemsList.toMutableList().add(item)
```

*itemlist* : list of your items

*item* : item you want to add

Comment: Didn't you miss an assignment? toMutableList() creates a copy of itemsList and doesn't change it, right?

Comment: I think you're correct, an assignment is missing and also, .add(item) returns a Boolean so this has to be done in multiple steps, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @PhilipRego don't use it in initialize. use it like this => aggList.toMutableList().add(user)
,
in initialize => var aggList: List<User> = emptyList<User>

Comment: It doesn't change anything about itemsList

Answer (score 11):

instead of using a regular list which is immutable just use an arrayListof which is mutable

so your regular list will become

```
var listofVehicleNames = arrayListOf("list items here")
```

then you can use the add function

```
listOfVehicleNames.add("what you want to add")
```

Answer (score 8):

you should use a MutableList like ArrayList

```
var listofVechileName:List<String>?=null
```

becomes

```
 var listofVechileName:ArrayList<String>?=null
```

and with that you can use the method add

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html

Comment: I didnt want to change too much author, but as someone makes me notice you should avoid to init to null, it would be better using lazeinit

Answer (score 4):

For any specific class, the following may help

```
 var newSearchData = List<FIRListValuesFromServer>()

        for (i in 0 until this.singleton.firListFromServer.size) {

            if (searchText.equals(this.singleton.firListFromServer.get(i).FIR_SRNO)) {

                newSearchData.toMutableList().add(this.singleton.firListFromServer.get(i))

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

val listofVechile = mutableListOf<String>()

Declare mutable list like that and you will be able to add elements to list :

listofVechile.add("car")

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = listOf("a")
list += "b"
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: @JeremyCaney no other answer here uses `+=` (exept a deleted one). other answers use `foo = foo + item`, but not `+=`.

Comment: @starball: The contributor should still explain why this is preferable over existing approaches. That will make this answer far more useful, and especially to readers new to the syntax.