# add null in the list of model data arrays kotlin android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Why can't I add null in the list of model data arrays in Kotlin language?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIIMB.png)

```
adapterPaging!!.setOnLoadMoreListener {
            var customersModels: List<CustomersModel> = ArrayList()
            customersModels.add(null)
        }
```

Comment: What does the compiler error tell you?

Comment: It does not compile, it gives an error in Kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an item to a list in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488291/how-to-add-an-item-to-a-list-in-kotlin)

Comment: @mrp Let me ask again: what is the compiler error and what does it tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var customersModels: List<CustomersModel> = ArrayList()
```

Your problem(?) here is polymorphism. You've defined `customersModels` as a `List`, which in Kotlin is **explicitly immutable**. [You can't `add` things to it.](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/)

> Methods in this interface support only read-only access to the list; read/write access is supported through the `MutableList` interface.

You're assigning an `ArrayList` to that variable, which is an object that *does* have the `add` method. And an `ArrayList` `is` a `List`, so you can do that. Like how a pencil *is* a writing tool that's erasable, if someone just needs something to write with, you can give them a pencil or a pen. All they've asked for is something that writes.

But the variable you're interacting with, `customersModels`, is explicitly a reference to a Kotlin `List` - a more restrictive subtype of `MutableList`*. It knows nothing about what that object *actually is*, just that it fits the immutable `List` type. That type **does not have an `add` method** so you can't call it. Same as how if you ask for a writing tool, you can't assume you'll be able to erase what you write.

---

So you have three options here (let's not get into reflection):

You can *cast* that variable to another type:

```
// or 'as ArrayList' if you really need to be that specific for some reason - you probably don't
(customersModels as MutableList).add(thing)
```

This is an *unchecked cast* - you're telling the compiler *"hey I know what this is, you don't but you're just gonna have to trust me on this one"*. This is unsafe, because there's no protection, the compiler can't do any checking and force you to handle potential problems. (Don't do this)

A better approach is to actually check as you cast - there are two ways to do this in Kotlin:

```
// confirm the object's type - this will result in a 'smart cast' because the compiler
// can see that you're handling it safely, so it basically allows you to treat
// myList as that type
if (myList is MutableList) myList.add(thing)

// same deal but you can cast with a null fallback if it fails, then null-check the result
(myList as? MutableList)?.add(thing)
```

This is good for things where you handle a more general type, but you might want to get specific and handle different member types in different ways. Especially common if you're using sealed classes.

---

The last approach is to just use the appropriate type in the first place!

```
// MutableList, since you want to mutate it by adding stuff
var customersModels: MutableList<CustomersModel> = ArrayList()
customersModels.add(null)
```

You're creating a list you want to change - so that's a `MutableList`, and that's what `customersModels` should be. This kind of thing can be internal - you can expose that list as a `List` rather than a `MutableList`, so that other stuff that uses it sees it as a fixed, immutable list. If you've used `LiveData` you've probably seen this approach:

```
private val _myData = MutableLiveData<String>("hi")
val myData: LiveData<String> = _myData
```

`myData` is literally pointing at that `MutableLiveData` object, but because its type is just `LiveData` (the immutable kind) that means stuff that accesses that public variable see an object they can't change. Really they could cast it to `MutableLiveData` and mess with it, but it's less a security feature and more of an organisational thing. Make it clear how stuff is meant to be used, how you interact with it, etc. If you want to update, go through a specific function, that kind of thing.

So use `List` if it's just a list that's meant to be read, not written to. If it will/might be changed, use the `MutableList` type. This makes it clearer about what's going on.

Also, generally you shouldn't use explicit types like `ArrayList` - Kotlin has a bunch of functions to generate `List`s and `MutableList`s, which makes it easier to reason about what you're doing and why:

```
val numbers = List(5) { it + 1 }
val greetings = mutableListOf("hi", "hey", "sup")
```

Notice I'm not specifying the type next to the variable, it's getting inferred by the function I'm using. So there's no "treat this mutable list as an immutable one" going on (unless you need to do that for a specific reason!)

Answer (score 0):

Your customersModel POJO class must contain a nullable data type. and also you have to declare list as follow :-
var customersModels: ArrayList<CustomersModel?> = ArrayList() CustomersModel must be  Then you will add null values to the list.

Comment: The list also needs to be declared as a `MutableList`, not a `List`.

Comment: Ya, I've edited my answer. You can also use ArrayList because ArrayList also does the insertion of data.